# Compare Strings After Character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I need to check email addresses against an internal known bad domain database.  My internal database has domains in the form of `myfreepaysite.com` just no @ sign.  I have been using this syntax to check, but it locks up my `SSMS` for roughly 90 seconds then unfreezes.  Is there a better way to do such?

```
Create Table #Testing
(
  emaildomain varchar(Max)
)
INSERT INTO #Testing VALUES ('myfreepaysite.com')


Create Table #DataToCheck
(
  fullemail varchar(max)
)
Insert Into #DataToCheck VALUES('rr1234@myfreepaysite.com')

Select Top 1 
fullemail
,SUBSTRING(fullemail, CHARINDEX('@', fullemail) + 1, LEN(fullemail))
FROM #DataToCheck
WHERE SUBSTRING(fullemail, CHARINDEX('@', fullemail) + 1, LEN(fullemail)) IN (Select emaildomain FROM #Testing)
```

Comment: How many email addresses approx. do you have to check when you do this? Obviously #DataToCheck just has one record here, but I'm assuming you have more in the real life data. Btw, why is "full email" a varchar(max), is it like this in the real life data?

Comment: @seventyeightist - #Testing has roughly 5,000 domains and #DataToCheck is never > 100 at one time.

Comment: Persist #Testing as an actual table (if it isn't already) and create a clustered index on "emaildomain". In #DataToCheck, create the "domain" (myfreepaysite.com) as you write to the table if possible, then inner join to the reference domain table. Could you post screenshots of the execution plans of your original and this suggestion?  Also, what do you mean by "locks up" SSMS - that the program is unresponsive or just that you are waiting for query results to come back?

Comment: It definitely shouldn't take 90 seconds to compare a table of 100 records to a table of 5,000 even with no indexes or optimisation.

Comment: Run the same query using sqlcmd from a dos box - is it slow? If not, you probably have an addin that is causing the problem in SSMS.

Answer (score 3):

Something that I've done in the past for searching emails by domain name is to reverse the email address and the domain. Then I can use the [LIKE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) with a wildcard and the resulting query should be sargable. You can read this [Brent Ozar post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/) about why this is helpful. The short version is reversing our email address and search term will allow us to use indexes. I don't think you'll need to do this based on the table sizes you mentioned in the comments but just in case you're curious you can create indexes on temp tables.

Disregarding indexes on the temp tables reversing things would make your original query look like this:

```
Create Table #Testing
(
  emaildomain varchar(100) -- You can't index max and it isn't needed
);
INSERT INTO #Testing
VALUES (REVERSE('@myfreepaysite.com')); -- Reversed & prepended the @ sign
                                        -- to ensure full domain matching

Create Table #DataToCheck
(
  fullemail varchar(200) -- You can't index max and it isn't needed
);
Insert Into #DataToCheck
VALUES(REVERSE('rr1234@myfreepaysite.com')); -- reversed

Select Top 1 
  REVERSE(d.fullemail) -- Changed
  ,REVERSE(t.emaildomain) --Changed
FROM #DataToCheck AS d
  INNER JOIN #Testing AS t ON d.fullemail LIKE t.emaildomain + '%'; -- Changed
```

That should be easier to read and perform better as well. Also note that I reduced the size of your `EmailDomain` and `FullEmail` columns. I did this because [you can't index a VARCHAR(MAX)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122003/72091) but more importantly you should scope your columns to the data sizes and types they'll actually contain.

Comment: I prepared an answer yesterday where I was going to suggest just simpler code without much (if any) improvement in efficiency. I'm glad I didn't post it. Your suggestion is far superior.

Comment: @AndriyM thank you that’s very kind of you to say. I appreciate the edit too.