# Does concating a string like this open me up to SQL injection?

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I recently answered a question with the following code sample:

```
Create Table #Testing
(
  emaildomain varchar(100) -- Still bigger than functionally needed but better than MAX
);
INSERT INTO #Testing VALUES (REVERSE('@myfreepaysite.com')); -- Changed


Create Table #DataToCheck
(
  fullemail varchar(200) -- Still bigger than functionally needed but better than MAX
);
Insert Into #DataToCheck VALUES(REVERSE('rr1234@myfreepaysite.com')); --Changed

Select Top 1 
  REVERSE(fullemail)
  , REVERSE(emaildomain)
FROM #DataToCheck
  INNER JOIN #Testing ON fullemail LIKE emaildomain + '%';
```

As I was writing that last line I wondered if concating `EmailDomain` column with the wildcard symbol was an opening for SQL injection. Is this something I should watch out for this type of code or will SQL Server evaluate this as a single unified parameter so I don't need to worry about using this approach?

Comment: A couple of comments, I know this isn't part of your question but (a) eckes is right that specifically here hope.com will match nohope.com, and (b) doing the reverse and trailing wildcard doesn't help with varchar(max) because you can't index that anyway (trailing wildcard helps you potentially get a narrow seek, on an index). That doesn't mean the approach is wrong, just that the data type choice is bad. There are RFCs / standards that dictate the max length of a domain name and the local part of an e-mail address, and it's a lot less than 2GB. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just updated [the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203795/72091) that I pulled this source from to include the '@' symbol which should fix the hope.com/nohope.com bug. With point b) are you saying this approach is useless, or only marginally helpful? I agree that functionally it is absurd to have a VARCHAR(MAX) for an email. :)

Comment: Just an observation that reversing a varchar(max) so that the wildcard is trailing instead of leading doesn't change anything, because a varchar(max) can't be indexed so a seek won't happen in any case. So if the OP is reversing all of those values solely to make the query more efficient, yes, it is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. That value will always be interpreted as a string and there's no way to put anything into the `emaildomain` column that could make the query execute unexpected code. It's either going to find matches or it's not.

Of course, this is relevant to the specific code sample you posted, and only that. You should always be concerned about any data you accept from a user... since you might not know where else it might be used now or in the future.

Comment: However the query makes not much sense, it might be suspectible to extension/missing delimiter attacks and has not very great performance ‚example.co‘ would match ‚example.com‘

Comment: Ok in that case Hope.com and Nohope.com

Comment: @Erik No the problem comes when you do (in your app or your stored procedure) `SET @sql = N'SELECT ...' + @userinput;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand perfect. Thank you. I knew your example in the comment was vulnerable.