# Change data column size cause warning on "change a column data type results in an index is too large"

Tags: sql-server

I only change the column size, why its warning "change a column data type results in an index is too large"?

What is the concept behind this, any relevant article for me to understand this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning points out, you have an index on the column `CityDesc` which is called `CityDes`. Indexes in SQL Server are limited to a [max of 900 bytes per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122003/150011) in any version of SQL Server prior to 2016 and still only [900 bytes for clustered indexes, and a max of 1,700 bytes for nonclustered indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#-objects) for version 2016 and later.

The [`NVARCHAR` data type consumes twice as many bytes as the length you define in it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (roughly). When your `CityDesc` field was only `NVARCHAR(300)` the length 300 x 2 = 600 < 900 and therefore was indexable. Now you're trying to increase the length to 500, and 500 x 2 = 1,000 > 900 therefore exceeding the index size limit, making it no longer indexable, hence the warning.

Your options are to proceed with the change which will drop the index as the warning specifies, or pick a smaller size for your column such as `NVARCHAR(400)`, which will then keep the index in place.